# Is it possible to have single repository for both relational and non-relation db in spring data?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, microservices

I Want to make my microservice compatible with both relational and non-relational databases,

Currently, I have five small modules which make a single microservice:

- Controller-module - This contains all my controllers and has a dependency on the service module
- Service module - This contains services which communicate with DB layer to get data or post data, and obviously has a dependency on data layer (common-db-modules)
- Common-db-modules- this module defines contracts (interfaces only) for datalayers to follow in order to be compatible with service
- Data-layer - this module provides concrete implementation of contracts defined by common-db-module. There could be multiple data-layers depending on the database. which means one for Mongo DB, one for MySQL, etc
- Packaging: number of packaging module is defined based on db used, packing packages

  - controller-module
  - Service-Module
  - One Data-Layer (DB for which this packaging is made)

My question: is there a way to eliminate this common contract for DB and have a single implementation of the Data layer which will serve both relational and non-relational DB?

Comment: Why you do not use the Repository Pattern?

Comment: you mean using spring data rest? My services migh have lots of manipulations, I am not sure whther this will be a good choice, but neverthless, will it work for both relational and non-relational db?

Comment: You can use generic repository and implement it for what you want, SQL or NoSQL.

Comment: That's what i have done, I have written implementation for SQL and NonSQL, what i want is the way to write one implementation which works for both SQL and NonSQL

Comment: @KumarGaurav you can have single repository, based on dialect query will be executed. Have you try something?

Comment: @Lemmy, i want something like that but unfortunately i am not finding any framework for writing that repository. Eg: If i take hibernate then it provides one solution for SQL (ORM) and another one for noSql (OGM). This is what thid question is asking, "Is there any framework"

Comment: Why did you have Data Layer ? Spring Data JPA generates DAO for you via repository classes

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to build data layer by your self, Spring already creates Data access object (DAO) for you. use JPA repository which are capable for fetching data from both sql and nosql.

kindly refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories

and you also needed to configure.. Database

Comment: its written there that it provides specific solution. there are two interface, one for jpa another for mongo. I will come to square zero only. and also for my mo go. implementation i used mongorepository. problem i want to solve is to write once and it should be applicable on both sql and nosql. just like single hibernate persistence layer is capable of working on mssql mysql oracle etx